# Why is my xslt selecting the child node of a node I haven't specified?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, oxygenxml

I used to use xslt a few years ago and while I wans't an expert I could write basic transformations. I am having issues now which I don't understand.

Here I am trying to extract a Dublin Core record from a foxml record. The Dublin Core record in in xml, and foxml is basically an xml standard that groups lots of xml records.

Here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foxml:digitalObject VERSION="1.1" PID="vital:26113"
xmlns:foxml="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml#"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml# http://www.fedora.info/definitions/1/0/foxml1-1.xsd">
<foxml:objectProperties>
    <foxml:property NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#state" VALUE="Active"/>
    <foxml:property NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#label" VALUE="DCity/DCCPC_DC.xml"/>
    <foxml:property NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#ownerId" VALUE=""/>
    <foxml:property NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#createdDate"
        VALUE="2016-09-06T19:49:51.257Z"/>
    <foxml:property NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/view#lastModifiedDate"
        VALUE="2016-09-27T13:23:10.950Z"/>
    <foxml:extproperty NAME="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type" VALUE="FedoraObject"/>
    <foxml:extproperty NAME="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#contentModel" VALUE=""/>
</foxml:objectProperties>
<foxml:datastream ID="DC" STATE="A" CONTROL_GROUP="X" VERSIONABLE="true">
    <foxml:datastreamVersion ID="DC.0" LABEL="Dublin Core for this Record"
        CREATED="2016-09-06T19:49:51.290Z" MIMETYPE="text/xml"
        FORMAT_URI="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" SIZE="653">
        <foxml:xmlContent>
            <oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                <dc:title>St. Patricks</dc:title>
                <dc:creator>Mary Mooney</dc:creator>
                <dc:publisher>Publisher</dc:publisher>
                <dc:format>Photograph</dc:format>
                <dc:identifier>123456</dc:identifier>
                <dc:identifier>100.jpg</dc:identifier>
                <dc:coverage>1984</dc:coverage>
                <dc:rights>Publisher</dc:rights>
            </oai_dc:dc>
        </foxml:xmlContent>
    </foxml:datastreamVersion>
    <foxml:datastreamVersion ID="DC.1" LABEL="Dublin Core for this Record"
        CREATED="2016-09-27T13:23:10.894Z" MIMETYPE="text/xml"
        FORMAT_URI="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" SIZE="653">
        <foxml:xmlContent>
            <oai_dc:dc xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                <dc:title>St Audoen&apos;s</dc:title>
                <dc:creator>William Mooney</dc:creator>
                <dc:publisher>Publisher</dc:publisher>
                <dc:format>Photograph</dc:format>
                <dc:identifier>10987654</dc:identifier>
                <dc:identifier>200.jpg</dc:identifier>
                <dc:coverage>1984</dc:coverage>
                <dc:rights>Publisher</dc:rights>
            </oai_dc:dc>
        </foxml:xmlContent>
    </foxml:datastreamVersion>
</foxml:datastream>
</foxml:digitalObject>
```

and here is my xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:audit="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/audit#" xmlns:premis="http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v1"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2"
xmlns:foxml="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml#"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml# http://www.fedora.info/definitions/1/0/foxml1-1.xsd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>
   <xsl:template match="/foxml:digitalObject/foxml:datastreamVersion[@ID eq DC.1]/foxml:xmlContent">
       <metadata>
         <xsl:value-of select="oai_dc:dc"/>
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </metadata>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect the DC section of the foxml:datastreamVersion with the ID=DC.1 to be returned. Instead I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                St. Patricks
                Mary Mooney
                Publisher
                Photograph
                123456
                100.jpg
                1984
                Publisher


                St Audoen's
                William Mooney
                Publisher
                Photograph
                10987654
                200.jpg
                1984
                Publisher
```

So I have two obvious problems.

1. why is it selecting material from the node that doesn't match the attribute I have selected?
2. why is it only returning the text, rather than the accompanying element tags etc?

I am using oXygen 19.1 with the Saxon-EE.9.7.0.19 transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have a problem with your match expression, it should be this...

```
 /foxml:digitalObject/foxml:datastream/foxml:datastreamVersion[@ID eq 'DC.1']/foxml:xmlContent
```

You had missed out `foxml:datastream` in the path. Also "DC.1" needed to be put in apostrophes to make it a string, as opposed to an element name.

However, in answer to your question "why is it selecting material from the node that doesn't match the attribute", the answer is "Because of XSLT's [Built-In Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule)"

When XSLT starts its processing it will look for a template matching the document node `/`. You have no such template in your XSLT, and so the default template kicks in. Effectively, it is equivalent of having these two templates in your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

These skip over elements, but output text where it finds it, which leads to all other text being output. To stop this happening, add this template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

(In XSLT 3.0, do `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />` instead)

As for the second question, when the template matches, you do `<xsl:value-of select="oai_dc:dc"/>` and that outputs all descendant text nodes. You should use `xsl:copy-of` instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:audit="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/audit#" xmlns:premis="http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs dc oai_dc audit premis foxml xsi"
    version="2"
    xmlns:foxml="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml#"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml# http://www.fedora.info/definitions/1/0/foxml1-1.xsd">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/foxml:digitalObject/foxml:datastream/foxml:datastreamVersion[@ID eq 'DC.1']/foxml:xmlContent">
    <metadata>
      <xsl:copy-of select="oai_dc:dc"/>
    </metadata>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, simply match the document node, and target the node you wish to copy with a select.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:audit="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/audit#" xmlns:premis="http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs dc oai_dc audit premis foxml xsi"
    version="2"
    xmlns:foxml="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml#"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/foxml# http://www.fedora.info/definitions/1/0/foxml1-1.xsd">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="foxml:digitalObject/foxml:datastream/foxml:datastreamVersion[@ID eq 'DC.1']/foxml:xmlContent" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foxml:xmlContent">
    <metadata>
      <xsl:copy-of select="oai_dc:dc"/>
    </metadata>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's wonderful Tim, thank you so much for your thorough and clear answer! you're a wonderful person!